# How to configure apache cache expire setting for browser using ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, apache2

I am unable to configure apache mod_cache to expire 1 day time downloaded content from the browser, Please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The `CacheDefaultExpire` directive specifies a default time, in seconds, to cache a document if neither an expiry date nor last-modified date are provided with the document. The value specified with the `CacheMaxExpire` directive does not override this setting.

`CacheDefaultExpire 86400` (seconds)